# save byte[] to Google Drive from AppEngine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

```
byte[] fileItemData = blobstoreService.fetchData(blobKey, 0, 999999);   
ByteArrayContent mediaContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileItemMimeType, fileItemData);
insert = driveService.files().insert(body, mediaContent);
File file = insert.execute();
```

-> why does the insert.execute() not catch Exception...? just does nothing.
-> when i leave the "fileItemData" i get an item in google drive. So what is wrong with it? I am  trying to upload to Google AppEngine and store to Google Drive on AppEngine.

Comment: I'm confused as to what's wrong -- are you getting an exception on `insert.execute()`? What do you mean about getting an item when you "leave" `fileItemData`?

Comment: if i insert without fileItemData - sorry i should say mediaContent - >insert = driveService.files().insert(body);< i will see the entry in google drive

Comment: i do not get an exception ... just nothing happens when inserting with mediacontent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try your code with a smaller data, for instance this:

```
ByteArrayContent mediaContent = ByteArrayContent.fromString("text/plain", "Hello World")
driveService.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
```

and let me know if that works...

Comment: Did not work. 

The line insert... followed by a log does only work if i 
`.insert(body).execute()` (next line with log is executed) instead of `.insert(body,mediaContent).execute()` 

> (next line with log not executed and no errorlog on appeEngine).

 
Using `.insert(body).execute()` creates a perfect google drive entry without content.
Google Drive just says as expected: 

> "Sorry, we were unable to find the document at the original source.
> Verify that the document still exists."

.

Comment: My guess is that an exception happens that is not catched. Have you tried surrounding the call with try {...} cache (Exception e) {//write e.getMessage() to log} ?

Comment: it is surrounded by:
 } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
 } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
 } catch (IOException e) { 
 } catch (Exception e) {

Comment: i removed these triggers /*
    * } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
    * } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
    * } catch (IOException e) {
    */
and only left "} catch (Exception e) {" now the "Hello World" was stored into Google Drive.

Comment: Same works for my "byte[] fileItemData = blobstoreService.fetchData(blobKey, 0, 999999);" ... last try is to readd all the catch (... i removed.. -> just to reproduce the problem

Comment: readded all chatch (... and it still works. So as of today i did not change anything and everything works. ... that's all we know :-)